# I am trying to set post terms to a custom taxonomy

Tags: functions, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a custom taxonomy that I would like to update on posts using a PHP function.  An example of what I am trying to achieve is the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 183
            [name] => Spotlight
            [slug] => spotlight
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 183
            [taxonomy] => deals_tiers
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 5
            [filter] => raw
            [term_order] => 0
        )    
)
```

I am trying to set this on posts that  have no data in these fields. This can be achieved in the backend by checking the "Spotlight" checkbox but I would like to do this via a function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On what event do you want to assign the terms to post? Or do you want to assign the terms to all posts without a term?

Comment: I have an event that is fired once a transaction is made. The function is actually in a conditional if a cookie is set and that is firing, I just don't know what to call to enter this data.

Comment: You will have to call wp_query with taxonomy parameters setting `field` as `term_id`, `terms` as `''` and `operator` as `=`.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I'm not sure I understand however. Would I call this instead of doing something like wp_set_post_terms? I was trying that and update_post_meta to no avail.

Comment: You are supposed to call wp_query like [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters). That will allow you to set up query data for `theloop` and in `theloop` you will call `wp_set_post_terms`